# AngularJS - Directive not loaded

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive, angular-directive

i'm working with directive on AngularJS, but the template don't load.

The code is simple, when i click on the newSearch() button a new Tab is created and it's content have to be loaded with a directive and it's template.

But, the directive don't work, i juste have my tag.

However, if i place manually the tag in client.html, the directive works fine.

I know i miss something important and need help to understand, so thx in advance for your support.

Here is my client.html :

```
<div class="client" ng-controller="ClientController">
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" disable="tab.disabled">
        <tab-heading ng-bind-html="tab.title">{{ tab.title }}</tab-heading>
        <div ng-bind-html="tab.content">{{ tab.content }}</div>
    </tab>
    <tab-heading>
        <button ng-click="newSearch()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </tab-heading>
</tabset>
</div>
```

And here is my Controller and some very simple Directive :

```js
app.controller('ClientController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {  
    var ctrl = this;

    $scope.tabs = [
        {
            title: $sce.trustAsHtml('Resume'),
            content: $sce.trustAsHtml('<client-resume></client-resume>')
        },
    ];
    ctrl.openView = function(title, content) {

        var tab = {
            title: $sce.trustAsHtml(title),
            content: $sce.trustAsHtml(content)
        };

        $scope.tabs.push(tab);
    };
    ctrl.closeView = function(index) {
        $scope.tabs.splice(index, 1);
    };
    $scope.newSearch = function() {
        ctrl.openView("Recherche", "<client-search></client-search>");
    };
    $scope.newFolder = function() { 
        ctrl.openView("Alfred Hitchcock", "<client-folder></client-folder>");
    };
}]);
app.directive('clientResume', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'modules/Client/partials/template/_resume.tpls.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: You are not closing your div's properly. To start with, please update that.

Comment: Ho damn, my bad, it's an old copy/paste...

app.directive('clientResume', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'modules/Client/partials/template/_resume.tpls.html';
    };
});

That's the current directive.

Comment: The same problem persists in your client.html

Comment: Sorry, the closure </div> was not in the "code" tag.

Comment: It's normal, i use the $scope.newSearch() (for example) to add a tab in the $scope.tabs array.

That's working fine. The tag <client-resume></client-resume> appear in the tab's content.
But the template is not loaded (even if i check on network tool with chrome).

Answer (score 0):

you must $compile content variable in your code,

like :

```
                        var templateElement = angular.element('<p>{{total}}</p>');
                    var clonedElement = $compile(templateElement)(scope, function (clonedElement, scope) {

                    });
```

Comment: Ho, ok. Do i have to use the link property ?